# Hibernate: group by & having criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-criteria

I have the following entities in my database:

- `Ticket`
- `TicketEntry`

Every `TicketEntry` references a `Ticket` and 1 `Ticket` has 0 or more ticket entries. I'm trying to figure out how I can retrieve all the tickets that have 1 `TicketEntry`. I've put together the SQL script but I don't know how I can convert this to Hibernate Criteria Restrictions.

```
SELECT ticket_id FROM ticket_entries
GROUP BY ticket_id
HAVING count(ticket_id) = 1;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I actually meant criteria restrictions. I didn't want to edit the question because it already had 2 answers.

Comment: Be careful linking documentation of other persistence providers as a means to document Hibernate behavior when in fact it may not always be an exact representation of how to do that in other providers.

Comment: @Ferre12 Must it use the deprecated Hibernate Criteria API?  This query would be much easier to write in HQL.

Comment: I don't really have a choice because I am building on other Criteria, so yeah I would appreciate it.

Comment: That's fine, I provided both.   I'm not sure what version of Hibernate you're using presently, but be mindful that the legacy Criteria API is deprecated and planned for removal soon.  Using JPA Criteria or JPQL/HQL as an alternative is much recommended.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm using an old version of Hibernate because it's a legacy application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your post, I am going to assume your entity model is similar to the following

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {
  /* other attributes */

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ticket")
  private List<TicketEntry> entries;
}

@Entity
public class TicketEntry {
  /* other attributes */

  @ManyToOne
  private Ticket ticket;
}
```

If you wish to use the Hibernate Criteria API, you would do this using:

```
Restrictions.sizeEq( "entries", 1 )
```

You can do this with Hibernate HQL as follows

```
SELECT t FROM Ticket t WHERE size(t.entries) = 1
```

The special `size()` function in HQL tests the size of the collection.

In both cases, the assumption here is that the root of the query that `sizeEq` and `size()` are being applied to is the parent `Ticket` in order to satisfy that you want all `Ticket` that have only `1` entry.